# many-to-many intersection query with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following classes :-

```
Blog.cs
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<BlogTag> BlogTags { get; set; }
```

and

```
BlogTag.cs
public int BlogTagId { get; set; }
public string BlogTagName { get; set; }
public Blog Blog { get; set; }
public int BlogId { get; set; }
```

Now I need to get a list of Blogs that contain the BlogTagName, so I tried the following but it is not working properly:-

```
 var tags = viewModel.BlogViewModel.BlogList.Where(post => post.BlogTags.All(tag => tag.BlogTagName.Contains(tagName)));
```

How can I get this working?

Thanks

Comment: I think the modelling can be refactored slightly. If it is many to many, the BlogTag class should not have a Blog. Theoritically, you could rather have a List<Blog>. Depends on whether you are always going to query top-down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `All` by `Any` sould do the trick

This will check if "at least one" blockTag of the blog contains your tagName.

With `All`, all of the blockTags from a blog should contain your tagName.

Comment: Yes it is working now.  But why?  When I had All was not returning any blog back

Comment: Thanks Raphael, it does!   Thanks for your help